# How do I find the URL (stream) of this radio station?

Tags: streaming, url

Do you guys know how to find the URL of this radio station? http://trap.fm/

I have been trying to watch some youtube videos but I failed to get the right one.

Mind anyone helping me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are m3u files to download on the right hand side:

[image: gui for download links]

For example the listen192.m3u links to this [download](http://radio.trap.fm/listen192.m3u). Your browser should ask you what to do with the download.

m3u is a simple text file containing the stream url:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,TRAP.FM - 192 kbps
http://stream.trap.fm:6002
```

You can open the m3u file in any media player, for example with [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/846712)

Comment: You comment is rally motivating. Thanks. Could you clarify why a downloadable m3u file is not the answer to the question on how to obtain a given stream url? This is as easy as a stream provider can make it for the user. But maybe the website looks different on his device, hence my question.

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish and you feed him for life.   The question asks ***How do you find the URL?***

Comment: @Scott That's why I asked in my first version. Because for me the link is just there with a black and white vlc icon. Not the slightest way of concealing the stream url and no voodoo needed to extract it from some json or whatever.

Comment: I can't open it for some reason, it shows some error. Are there not any other links?

Comment: What is the error message? Is it an error from your browser trying to download or from your media player trying to open the file? Which media player are you using?

Comment: @antonis-m You can right-click the correct icon and `Save link as...` with most browsers to save the playlist file itself. If you're using VLC (as suggested), you can use just double-click the `.m3u` playlist to begin streaming. Alternately, you can use e.g. `Media --> Open Network Stream... --> http://stream.trap.fm:6002 --> Play` to play the stream in VLC as well. If you want to record the stream, you can use ex. [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) with e.g.`ffmpeg -i http://stream.trap.fm:6002 -c copy output.mp3`. Windows builds of ffmpeg are [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: @antonis-m Regarding "other" links, `stream.trap.fm:6002` is a raw `.mp3` stream. Links to other playlist formats are under the different icons.